# Кластеризация матриц

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Добрый день.

Не могу сообразить, как должен выглядеть правильный алгоритм (язык C#, но это неважно).

Имеется N элементов z1, z2, ..., zN. Два элемента zi и zj могут иметь отношение связанности (а могут не иметь). Отношение связанности является транзитивным. Т.е. если zi и zj связаны, и также zj и zk связаны, тогда zi и zk также являются связанными.

Отношения могут быть выражены матрицей, где 1 обозначает связанность, 0 - её отсутствие. Имея подобную матрицу, необходимо посчитать количество кластеров, т.е. подмножеств элементов; в каждом кластере все элементы связаны друг с другом, но не связаны с элементами из других кластеров.

Пример 1: 4 элемента

```
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

Отсюда, можно видеть, что связаны элементы 1 и 2, также 2 и 3 => связаны 1,2, и 3, образуя 1-й кластер. Элемент 4 не связан ни с кем, и образует 2-й кластер из одного элемента.

Пример 2: 3 элемента

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

тут, как можно видеть, имеются три кластера из одного элемента каждый.

Comment: Вы можете поизучать работы Миркина. http://www.twirpx.com/file/283458/

Answer (score 2):

Ну это же обычный неориентированный граф, матрица инцеденций, поиск связных компонентов... Просто выполняете поиск в глубину (или в ширину).

Описания есть везде, см., например, [тут](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/dfs).

Реализовать могу только на C++, C# могу только читать, но не писать :)

Answer (score 0):

Написал такую реализацию на JavaScript:

```
var arr = [[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]];
//var arr = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]];
//var arr  = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]];


var check = function(i) {   

    var was1 = false;

    for (var j=0; j<arr.length;j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
            was1 = true;
            arr[i][j] = 0;
            check(j);
        }
    }   
    if (was1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

var count = 0;

for (var i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {   
    count += check(i);  
}

alert(count);
```